# When to trust Integrate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to get an analytical expression for the following integral:

```
f = 16 k Abs[Cos[t] + Sqrt[2] Sin[t] Cos[k z]]^5/Pi;
Integrate[f, {z, 0, 2 Pi/k}, Assumptions -> k > 0 && t > 0]
```

The answer Mathematica gives is not correct for `t>ArcTan[1/Sqrt[2]]`:

```
(* ConditionalExpression[-((-90 Cos[t] + 55 Cos[3 t] + 3 Cos[5 t])/Sign[Cos[t] + Sqrt[2] Sin[t]]^5), Cos[t] + Sqrt[2] Sin[t] != 0] *)

N@% /. t -> 1

(* 102.226 *)

NIntegrate[f /. {t -> 1, k -> 2}, {z, 0, 2 Pi/2}]

(* 103.146 *)
```

(these two numerical results should be equal.) The answer is independent of `k` (e.g. on change of variables to `k z`). If I set `k=1` for `Integrate`, it gives me the correct (rather complicated) expression. Also, I know I can get a simpler expression by splitting the integral into two regions using `ArcCos[-Cot[t]/Sqrt[2]]`. However, I want to know when I can't trust `Integrate`.

Comment: I guess the common answer "never trust any CAS result, ever" is not really what you're looking for, right?

Answer (score 4):

Making use of `RealAbs` introduced in 2017 instead of `Abs`, we obtain the same results symbolically and numerically.

```
f = 16 k RealAbs[Cos[t] + Sqrt[2] Sin[t] Cos[k z]]^5/Pi;
Integrate[f /. t -> 1, {z, 0, 2 Pi/k}, Assumptions -> k > 0 ]
```

> A long exppression

```
N[%]
```

> 103.146 + 4.45408*10^-15 I